# String Index out of Range - Python 3.x.x with swapcase() function

Tags: python, string

I am trying to capitalize every other letter of a string which is given by and input. For some reason it give me the error 'string index out of range' and i have no idea why! the range is set from 0 to the length of the string so that cant be possible i thought!

```
s = input('Please enter a string: ')
p=s.lower()
o=s.upper()
q=p
k=len(s)
l=1

for x in range(0,k):
    if l%2==0:
        q=q[x].swapcase()
        l+=1
    else:
        l+=1

print(q)
```

Comment: `q=q[x]`: 1'st time you do that (for `x = 0`), you reduced *q* to `q[0]` (one char), then when `x = 1`, and you do it again you get the *IndexOutOfRange*. What do you mean by "*capitalize every other letter*"? Could you give a sample string as an example and an expected output? Are you looking for smth like `s1 = "".join([e if i % 2 else e.upper() for i, e in enumerate(s)])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
 q=q[x].swapcase()
```

`q` becomes a single letter.

The next time around you try:

```
q[1]
```

but there is no `q[1]` because you made it a single letter.

This is one of several reasons why python encourages you to avoid creating index variables and instead looping over the items themselves.  If you do that and give your variables more descriptive names, these kind of error are easier to catch. For example:

```
s = input('Please enter a string: ')
lower_case = s.lower()

new_string = ""

for index, letter in enumerate(lower_case):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        new_string += letter.swapcase()
    else:
        new_string += letter
print(new_string)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it, I kind of realized that it would be a one char variable and tried to change it to.
``` q[x]=q[x].swapcase() ``` but that seemed to fail too. your explanation helped out alot!